# Using django-webtest with BDD (behave) step definitions

Tags: python, django, bdd

How can I get the benefits of using Webtest inside BDD step definitions (using `behave-django`), given that I don't have a TestCase to inherit the WebTest class inside the step definition?

Is there something I can do in `environment.py` to replace the default test client with the WebTest one?

Comment: *The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: @aaron I don't know how to make it any clearer. I want to be able to use the functionality provided by `django-webtest` inside my `behave-django` step definitions, and I can't figure out an obvious way of doing that. It's possible that someone has done that and I'd like to know how.